# Cannot change the state of a react component using setState() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner and I am trying to see how stateful components work in react. I have implemented a simple functionality where I would click a button and change the state of the content that I am rendering on the DOM.

But, after using the `setState` method in the event handler, the output doesn't give the desired results.

Here is the code -

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      content: "Initial Content"
    };
  }

  clickHandler()
  {
    this.setState({
      content: "Final Content"
    })
    console.log("Clicked")
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>The content inside the state is: {this.state.content}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.clickHandler} >Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please correct me if there are some issues in the code

Comment: Bind your `clickHandler` handler to `this` in the constructor or use an arrow function to call it.

Comment: Potential typo: `clickHandler()` may need to be `clickHandler = () => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost correct. You just need to bind the event handler, to ensure that `this` refers to the component instance within the event handler.
Here is the updated version:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "Initial Content"
    };
    // Binding the event handler to the component instance
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      content: "Final Content"
    });
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The content inside the state is: {this.state.content}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```